# Nuget package init.ps1 script and PackageReference modification

Tags: powershell, nuget, packagereference

I want to have referenced dll(s) in my package in "copy local = false" mode. In other words, I don't want that the dll(s) my package ships is/are copied into a output directory after the build.

The way this can be done in "packages.config" scenario is by having a following script in the tools/install.ps1 file.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
$asms = $package.AssemblyReferences | %{$_.Name} 
foreach ($reference in $project.Object.References) 
{
    if ($asms -contains $reference.Name + ".dll") 
    {
        $reference.CopyLocal = $false;
    }
}
```

I know that the newest Nuget version with PackageReference functionality uses only init.ps1 script. But I don't have any clue what so ever, what shall I write into that script.

I also know that the package user can add...

```
<ExcludeAssets>Runtime</ExcludeAssets>
```

to make this happen. But as a package author, I really would like to enforce that behaviour. So would it be possible to add that in the script?